# Sensor return value can not be stored/retreived using PokeReturnValue

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Below code creates the dag (the graph is also attached) which contains 2 PythonSensors and a PythonOperator.

First Sensors creates a random integer list as data and a random boolean with 50% chance of success. It logs generated values and returns `PokeReturnValue`
Second sensor and Python operator both tries to get data from xcom and log them.

[Graph of DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFp8h.png)

```
# region IMPORTS
import random
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG

from heliocampus.configuration.constants import Constants
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor
from airflow.sensors.base import PokeReturnValue

from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

from box import Box
# endregion

# region configuration
constants = Constants()

dagconfig = Box({ "Code":"Test" })
# endregion

def main() -> DAG:
    
    # region default_args
    args = dict()
    args['start_date'] = datetime(2021, 1, 1)
    # endregion
    
    with DAG(dag_id=dagconfig.Code, schedule_interval="@once", default_args=args, tags=['test', 'V0.1.4']) as dag:
        start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")

        # region Sensors
        check_all_expired_tables = PythonSensor(
            task_id="CHECK_ALL_EXPIRED_TABLES",
            poke_interval=timedelta(seconds=20).total_seconds(),
            timeout=timedelta(minutes=1).total_seconds(),
            mode="reschedule",
        
            python_callable=check_expired_tables,
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS
        )

        check_all_expired_tables_notification = PythonOperator(
            task_id="CHECK_ALL_EXPIRED_TABLES_NOTIFICATION", 
            python_callable=sensor_result_nofitication,
            op_kwargs={"notification_source":"CHECK_ALL_EXPIRED_TABLES"},
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_FAILED
        )

        verify_ods_operator = PythonSensor(
            task_id="VERIFY_ODS",
            poke_interval=timedelta(seconds=30).total_seconds(),
            timeout=timedelta(hours=2).total_seconds(),
            mode="reschedule",
        
            python_callable=verify_ods,
            op_kwargs={"notification_source":"CHECK_ALL_EXPIRED_TABLES"},
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS
        )
        # endregion

        end = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")

        start >> check_all_expired_tables >> verify_ods_operator >> end
        check_all_expired_tables >> check_all_expired_tables_notification

        return dag

# region Notifications
def sensor_result_nofitication(ti, notification_source):
    actual_xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=[notification_source])
    logging.info(f"sensor_result_nofitication : Sensor without key from {notification_source} is {actual_xcom_value}")
 
    actual_xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(key='return_value', task_ids=[notification_source])
    logging.info(f"sensor_result_nofitication : Sensor return_value from {notification_source} is {actual_xcom_value}")
# endregion

def check_expired_tables():
    randomlist = random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)
    randomResult = random.randint(0, 100) > 50

    logging.info(f"check_expired_tables : returning PokeReturnValue(is_done={randomResult}, xcom_value={randomlist})")

    return PokeReturnValue(is_done=randomResult, xcom_value=randomlist)

def verify_ods(ti, notification_source):
    actual_xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=[notification_source])
    logging.info(f"verify_ods : Sensor without key from {notification_source} is {actual_xcom_value}")
 
    actual_xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(key='return_value', task_ids=[notification_source])
    logging.info(f"verify_ods : Sensor return_value from {notification_source} is {actual_xcom_value}")
    
    rnd = random.randint(0, 100)
    
    logging.info("Random Number : {num}".format(num=rnd))
    
    return (rnd > 20)

main()
```

Regardless of whether the first sensor is successfull or not the data from xcom can not be logged in the second sensor or python operator.

I don't know if the problem is on the pushing side or pulling side.
I can not see any rows inserted in airflow database (xcom table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lives in the [PythonSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/_modules/airflow/sensors/python.html#PythonSensor) which is coercing the return of the python callable to boolean without checking its type first:

```
return_value = self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
return PokeReturnValue(bool(return_value))
```

To get the expected behavior something like this needs to be added to the PythonSensor:

```
return return_value if isinstance(return_value, PokeReturnValue) else PokeReturnValue(bool(return_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been reading these code for some time. :D
In [PokeReturnValue class](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f4be70aa74885671d16557795f694ada98769caa/airflow/sensors/base.py#L73)
this function allows the conversion you mentioned I guess. Besides there is no error raised in the execution.

Comment: I see now. Somehow I always went for [BaseSensorOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f4be70aa74885671d16557795f694ada98769caa/airflow/sensors/base.py#L77) while I am thinking that I am reading [PythonSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f4be70aa74885671d16557795f694ada98769caa/airflow/sensors/python.py#L27).

Now I understand and I think you are correct. The data portion of return value is skipped out by PythonSensor.